# Large file reading inconsistency in java

Tags: java, applet

I'm kind of stuck in a problem for some days, and I have no idea what to do.

Purpose is to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage, but because it's a large file, and i want some efficiency, I use a thread to read it, and I pre slice the file in chunks of 2Mo. These chunks are stored in a little queue (about 2 to 5 slots) and can be access by my uploader class (the one who makes PUT requests)

But (because there's always one) the chunks are not consistent on every computer. I tried many things, BufferedInputStream, PushBackInputStream, FileChannel (with or without MappedByteBuffer) there's nothing to do, impacted computers fails somewhere during reading, and the last part (who is smaller than a normal chunk) is always larger than expected (so the total number of bytes read exceeds the original calculated file size).

I don't know why, but on some computers (significant number) it seem the file grow during reading. 
Did I miss something ? What am I doing wrong ? Can I truncate the remaining bytes ? But what to do if it's suddenly smaller than expected ?
I'm out of ideas, so I request yours :)

Oh, little tricks, due to resume ability during upload, I must be able to get back in my reading, so it's reduce the number of class I can use (mark supported, or position in case of fileChannel).

If you have any advise on CPU and Memory optimisation, you're welcome too :) (There's not all of it, but the remaining it's just BlockingQueue implementation with q)

Here is a past of my Reader: 
http://paste.awesom.eu/Teraglehn/pw09&ln

And the interesting part :

```
public void run() {
    try {
        byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkSize];
        int read;
        int r;
        long skipped;
        while (!shouldStop && !finishReading && !stopped) {
            if(size()>=maxSize){
                continue;
            }
            read = 0;
            System.out.println("[available1] "+available);
            System.out.println("[available2] "+inputStream.available());
            if(pendingFix !=0){
                System.out.println(String.format("Fix of %d bytes asked", pendingFix));
                clear();
                if (pendingFix > 0 ) {
                    pendingFix = Math.min(pendingFix, (int) available);
                    skipped = inputStream.skip((long) pendingFix);
                    if(skipped != pendingFix){
                        throw new IOException(String.format("Ask fix of %d bytes has not been completely done (%d bytes actually skipped for unknown reason)", pendingFix, skipped));
                    }
                    incrementCursor(pendingFix);
                }else {
                    decrementCursor(Math.min(cursor, -pendingFix));
                    inputStream.reset();
                    skipped = inputStream.skip(cursor);
                    if(skipped != cursor){
                        throw new IOException(String.format("Ask fix of %d bytes has not been completely done (%d bytes actually back skipped for unknown reason)", pendingFix, cursor-skipped));
                    }
                }
                pendingFix = 0;
            }
            while(read < chunkSize){
                r = inputStream.read(chunk, read, chunkSize-read);
                if(r<0) {
                    read = (read > 0)? read : r;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    read +=r;
                }
            }

            if(pendingFix!=0) continue;
            if(read != chunkSize){ // Probably end of file
                if(read == -1){
                    finishReading = true;
                }else if(available == read){
                    System.out.println("Partial chunk (end)");
                    incrementCursor(read);
                    put(Arrays.copyOfRange(chunk, 0, read));
                    finishReading = true;
                }else {
                    throw new IOException(String.format("Only %d bytes have been read on %d bytes asked for unknown reason, %d bytes available", read, chunkSize, available));
                }
            }else {
                System.out.println("Full chunk (running)");
                put(chunk.clone());
                incrementCursor(read);
            }
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        this.interrupt();
        errors.add(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    stopped = true;
}
```

PS : There's something fun with all this, I upload session by session, and a session is a folder with one or more large file, it's always the last file which fails....

Comment: This is all far too complicated. The fundamental thing you need to know is that read() isn't obliged to fill the buffer.

Comment: I know that, thats why there's a while. but why it reading more than it should remain to read in file ? that's the question ! 
PS : And why only whit some computers ? I even try to run the reader in an IDE on an impacted pc, with same file to upload and it perfectly works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a mess that works when all things happen the certain way, but if something doesn't do what you expect, it will fail. You're using `available()` which is most likely wrong or at least useless.

Your read loop is also wrong, since it's filling the `chunk` array, but assuming that each read fills it completely (if not, the previous bytes are overwritten).

Your `// Probably end of file` comment means that you have a logic problem. So I'd recommend writing out the logic in plain English, then rewriting the code.

Comment: Gosh, sorry for the reading while, I edited that.
But for the available() i use it only in log to see what's going on with input stream, I know it do not guarantee to return the real size remaining. 
And for the comment... mmh i don't really know why it's here in fact, i could just write "End of file". But InputStream do not specify what it should read less than expected, so may be there's case it's not the end of file...

Comment: `InputStream` returns -1 on read at EOF. As for `available()` it returns the amount of bytes that can be read without blocking. It's rarely useful. Simplify your logic and it'll be easier to see where things go wrong.

Comment: I'll try. No, I'll do.